# Python 3.6 - Scrapy: navigate two times with spider before scraping content

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and I already built a spider that first extracts a list of urls in the start_url, navigates through each of these urls and scrapes content.

However, I need to change the logic of my new spider a little bit. The spider has to extract a list of urls in the start_url, must visit each of this urls, and from here has to extract and visit another url before starting to scrape content:

```
import scrapy

class KickerbotSpiderStats(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'matches-stats2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.kicker.de']
    start_urls = ['http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/wm/spiele/weltmeisterschaft/2014/-1/0/spieltag.html']

    # Step 1 // Go to Site with all matches and extract URL of each of them
    def parse(self, response):
        for match in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "aligncenter", " " ))]//a/@href').extract():
             yield scrapy.Request("http://www.kicker.de" + match, callback=self.parse_matchpage)

     # Step 2 // From each match URL, get URL for match stats 
    def parse_matchpage(self, response):
        for statsPage in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "nav4tab-sel", " " ))]//a/@href').extract():
             yield scrapy.Request("http://www.kicker.de" + statsPage, callback=self.parse_statspage)

    # Step 3 // Parse Stats from match 
    def parse_statspage(self, response):


        yield {
                'matchId' : (response.url).split("/")[-2],
                'local' : response.xpath('//*[(@id = "SpielpaarungLiveTitleRow")]//a/text()').extract_first().strip()
            }
```

I added this new step as in my working spider, but I am not getting any data back. Spider is crawling as before (200 response), but just for the first step, and is not navigating through the stats page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The second xpath is returning empty list, try this: `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "nav4tab-sel", " " ))]/@href`, also the url on step 2 is the same of step 1?

Comment: Try updating your post bringing little more clarity, otherwise one has to inspect element and apply your xpath in the broser console to find out which links you wanna parse. You should describe mentioning the visible text so that it is easier to find out what you wanna achieve. Thanks.